# Generating spatially correlated data with assigned spatial covariance

Tags: spatial, random-generation

I should generate data in the form $Z=Z(x,y)$ or $Z=Z(x)$ where $x,y$ are spatial variable, so that the spatial covariance results to be equal to an assigned function of the distance $h$ between two points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$, for example $Cov(h) = a*\exp(-h/b)$.
The spatial covariance is $E[(Z(x)-\mu)(Z(x+h) - \mu)]$, with $\mu = E[T(x)] = E[T(x+h)]$.
The problem is similar to the problem to generate data with assigned lag correlation in 1D case.

I should include that the my analytical point of view of this problem is the following:
$E[T(x)T(x+h)] = a*\exp(-h/b)$, $\forall h >0$ which is $\int_{\Omega} t f_{T(x)T(x+h)}(t)dt = a*\exp(-h/b)$ subject to $\mu = 0$ that is $\int_{\Omega} t f_{T(x)}(t)dt = 0$, $\forall x$.

I also have to mention that I know to generate two random arrays when their cross-correlation ($\rho(x,y)$, Pearson correlation index, that is proportional to the covariance of the two arrays) is assigned. This can be done using the function $\texttt{copularnd}$ in $\texttt{Matlab}$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? You end by saying you know how to generate part of it...

Comment: Actually I know only how to generate two correlated arrays. What I should do is to generate a random field (a 2d array with 2d coordinates) having a prescribed spatial covariance. Here is where I'm stuck. I do not know to generate these spatially correlated data. I know that in literature there is the matrix decomposition method but I don't have access to the article and hence to the algorithm, by the way in this other article (An effcient and accurate algorithm for generating
spatially-correlated random fields, Fang, Tacher) they explain a hybrid method but I don't understand the algorithm.